# Python Type Annotations: Mark item in tuple as None

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I type annotate a tuple on a return where either of them might be None?

```
from typing import Tuple

def foo(bar:int) -> Tuple[int:
    if bar > 10:
      return 1, None
    elif bar < 5:
      return None, 1
    else:
      return 1, 2
```

Comment: `tuple[Optional[int], Optional[int]` or in Python 3.10 + , `tuple[int|None, int|None]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def foo(bar:int) -> tuple[int | None, int | None]:
if bar > 10:
  return 1, None
elif bar < 5:
  return None, 1
else:
  return 1, 2
```

Like this ?